# Can't get amChart to fill based on function

Tags: javascript

For a while now I'm trying to fill an amChart based on a `javascript` function that I've made. What I want is to set a lot of the chartproperties that don't change, as a variable, which I can use in a lot of functions that make or fill a chart.  My code is:

```
var chartProperties = {
    "theme": "light",
    "type": "serial",
    "startDuration": 1,
    "dataProvider": [],
    "rotate": false,
    "categoryField": "organisatie",
      "valueAxes": [ {
        "gridColor": "#FFFFF",
        "minimum": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0.2,
        "dashLength": 0
      } ],
      "gridAboveGraphs": true,
      "startDuration": 1,
      "graphs": [ {
        "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "fillColorsField": "fillcolor", //Dit veld heb ik meegegeven vanuit SQL functie en bevat de HEX kleurcodes BD
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "score"
      } ],
      "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "zoomable": false
      },
      "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "tickPosition": "start",
        "tickLength": 20
      },
      "export": {
        "enabled": true
      }

};

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartaveragescore", chartProperties);
var organization = $("#organization").val();
var indicator = $("#indicators").val();
var funcid = "fill_chart_average_score";

var dataChart = $.getJSON('functions/getfunctions.php', {
    "organization":organization,
    "indicator":indicator,
    "funcid":funcid});

function updateOrganizationAverageScore() {

    chart.dataProvider =  dataChart;
    chart.validateData();

}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Can I set the $.getJSON as a variable? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it myself. I looked here on Stack and discovered that I can't set a directly `var =` with `$.getJSON` and then use it later one because I'm missing the callback.

My code that works now is:

```
function updateOrganizationAverageScore() {

    var organization = $("#organization").val();
    var indicator = $("#indicators").val();
    var funcid = "fill_chart_average_score";

    //console.log('changed'); 
    $.getJSON('functions/getfunctions.php', {
        "organization":organization,
        "indicator":indicator,
        "funcid":funcid},

    function(dataChart) {

            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartaveragescore", chartProperties);
            chart.dataProvider = dataChart;
            chart.validateData();
            chart.startDuration = 1;
    });
}
```